# How to pass title and description data of an annotation to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I want to pass data to my `DetailsViewController` from a selected annotation in `MapViewController`.

I am trying to hold on to the data of a selected annotation with this code below.
I have also added a prepare for segue method.

I am retrieving the data from Firebase so each annotation has a different title and description.

The `titleLabel` and `descriptionLabel` wont display the text on DetailsViewController.

I am new to programming, any help will be much appreciated!
Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

---

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    
    var selectedAnnotation = view.annotation
    
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if (segue.identifier == "goToDetails") {
           
        let detailsVC = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
            
            detailsVC.TitleLabel.text = selectedAnnotation?.title as! String
            detailsVC.DescriptionLabel.text = selectedAnnotation?.subtitle as! String
        }
        
    }
    
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetails", sender: nil)
    
    
   }
```

Comment: Why is `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { ... }` INSIDE `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) { ... }` ? It should be at the same level. Also, do you have errors? Because a common mistake here, is that `TitleLabel` and `DescriptionLabel` aren't loaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create two string variables inside the DetailsViewController.

   ```
   var detailTitle = ""

   var detailDescription = ""
   ```
2. In your first controller do this:

   ```
   var selectedTitle = ""

   var selectedDescription = ""

   func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

      if segue.identifier == "goToDetails" {
         let detailsVC = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
         detailsVC.detailTitle = selectedTitle
         detailsVC.detailDescription = selectedDescription
      }
   }

   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

      if let selectedAnnotation = view.annotation {

         if let title = selectedAnnotation.title {
           self.selectedTitle = title
         }

         if subtitle = selectedAnnotation.subtitle {
           self.selectedDescription = subtitle
         } 
      }

      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetails", sender: nil)
   }
   ```
3. The problem is, you're trying to set your text without labels being created.In your second viewcontroller (DetailsViewController) do this, so labels are created and you can give them your texts

   ```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.titleLabel.text = detailTitle
       self.descriptionLabel.text = detailDescription
    }
   ```